# Sticky block on JS

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

hello
i want to make a sticky block using this script

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
var sb_m = 80; /* top and bottom padding */
var mb = 300; /* footer height with a margin */
var st = $(window).scrollTop();
var sb = $(".loginform");
var sbi = $(".loginform #loginform");
var sb_ot = sb.offset().top;
var sbi_ot = sbi.offset().top;
var sb_h = sb.height();

if(sb_h + $(document).scrollTop() + sb_m + mb < $(document).height()) {
    if(st > sb_ot) {
        var h = Math.round(st - sb_ot) + sb_m;
        sb.css({"paddingTop" : h});
    }
    else {
        sb.css({"paddingTop" : 0});
    }
}
});
```

on naked HTML [all work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/trauka/nqu6jce4/11/)

if add a script to site (use wordpress) appears an infinite scroll

[here can see problem](http://u1454804.isp.regruhosting.ru/)

problem appears if add an element to footer through widgets

please tell me what is problem?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly it's not ideal to work with padding-top, you should use top (with the element set as position:relative or absolute);

If you don't care about supporting IE, the easiest way is to use position:sticky; which does all the work for you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

If you prefer to do it yourself, I'd suggest working this way:

1. store in variables the current offset().top and .left of the soon-to-be sticky element, outside any onScroll handlers.
2. When this condition is true:

$(window.scrollTop() >= theElementOffsetTopValueYouStored)

set the element as position: fixed and set the left: and top: properties of the element that should become sticky with the values you stored before. Then add your condition to make sure it stops when it reaches the end of the document, checking if element.offset().top + element.height > document.height

Please consider this is from memory, you might need to tweak a few things here and there to make it work properly.

Comment: of course with position:fixed everything would be easier
but it is in this example that cannot use it
all only via paddings